# Optimization of a large database query

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask if there is any way to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_BIG_RESULT DISTINCT u.spy_tech,
                               u.computer_tech,
                               u.military_tech,
                               u.defence_tech,
                               u.shield_tech,
                               u.energy_tech,
                               u.hyperspace_tech,
                               u.combustion_tech,
                               u.impulse_motor_tech,
                               u.hyperspace_motor_tech,
                               u.laser_tech,
                               u.ionic_tech,
                               u.buster_tech,
                               u.intergalactic_tech,
                               u.expedition_tech,
                               u.metal_proc_tech,
                               u.crystal_proc_tech,
                               u.deuterium_proc_tech,
                               u.technologia_bankowa,
                               u.technologia_kolonizacyjna,
                               u.technologia_optymalizacji,
                               u.technologia_otchlani,
                               u.graviton_tech,
                               SUM(p.small_ship_cargo)        as small_ship_cargo,
                               SUM(p.big_ship_cargo)          as big_ship_cargo,
                               SUM(p.light_hunter)            as light_hunter,
                               SUM(p.heavy_hunter)            as heavy_hunter,
                               SUM(p.crusher)                 as crusher,
                               SUM(p.battle_ship)             as battle_ship,
                               SUM(p.colonizer)               as colonizer,
                               SUM(p.recycler)                as recycler,
                               SUM(p.spy_sonde)               as spy_sonde,
                               SUM(p.bomber_ship)             as bomber_ship,
                               SUM(p.solar_satelit)           as solar_satelit,
                               SUM(p.destructor)              as destructor,
                               SUM(p.dearth_star)             as dearth_star,
                               SUM(p.battleship)              as battleship,
                               SUM(p.lune_noir)               as lune_noir,
                               SUM(p.ev_transporter)          as ev_transporter,
                               SUM(p.star_crasher)            as star_crasher,
                               SUM(p.giga_recykler)           as giga_recykler,
                               SUM(p.dm_ship)                 as dm_ship,
                               SUM(p.apocalypse)              as apocalypse,
                               SUM(p.annihilator)             as annihilator,
                               SUM(p.devastator)              as devastator,
                               SUM(p.fleet_save)              as fleet_save,
                               u.r_badawczy,
                               u.r_budowlany,
                               u.r_militarny,
                               u.r_obrony,
                               u.r_paliwowy,
                               u.r_gospodarczy,
                               u.r_planetarny,
                               u.r_magazynowy,
                               u.r_energetyczny,
                               u.r_ekonomiczny,
                               u.r_odkrywczy,
                               u.r_max,
                               u.r_speed,
                               u.r_moon,
                               u.r_dm,
                               u.r_terra,
                               SUM(p.misil_launcher)          as misil_launcher,
                               SUM(p.small_laser)             as small_laser,
                               SUM(p.big_laser)               as big_laser,
                               SUM(p.gauss_canyon)            as gauss_canyon,
                               SUM(p.ionic_canyon)            as ionic_canyon,
                               SUM(p.buster_canyon)           as buster_canyon,
                               SUM(p.small_protection_shield) as small_protection_shield,
                               SUM(p.big_protection_shield)   as big_protection_shield,
                               SUM(p.planet_protector)        as planet_protector,
                               SUM(p.graviton_canyon)         as graviton_canyon,
                               SUM(p.orbital_station)         as orbital_station,
                               SUM(p.dzialo_pulsacyjne)       as dzialo_pulsacyjne,
                               SUM(p.dzialo_fotonowe)         as dzialo_fotonowe,
                               SUM(p.interceptor_misil)       as interceptor_misil,
                               SUM(p.interplanetary_misil)    as interplanetary_misil,
                               u.id,
                               u.ally_id,
                               u.onlinetime,
                               s.tech_rank                    AS old_tech_rank,
                               s.build_rank                   AS old_build_rank,
                               s.defs_rank                    AS old_defs_rank,
                               s.fleet_rank                   AS old_fleet_rank,
                               s.total_rank                   AS old_total_rank,
                               s.total_points_old             AS total_points_old,
                               s.fleet_points_old             AS fleet_points_old,
                               s.defs_points_old              AS defs_points_old,
                               s.build_points_old             AS build_points_old,
                               s.tech_points_old              AS tech_points_old
FROM test_users as u
         LEFT JOIN test_statpoints as s ON s.stat_type = 1 AND s.id_owner = u.id
         LEFT JOIN test_planets as p ON u.id = p.id_owner
WHERE u.user_lastip != "127.0.0.1"
  AND u.bana = "0"
  AND u.authlevel = "0"
  AND u.universe = "1"
GROUP BY s.id_owner, u.id
```

On my VPS, the query takes 8 seconds and the result is about 10,000 results. Although I improved the machine twice, to 8x2,4CPU, 16gb RAM, the query time has not changed.
So I thought to optimize the above-mentioned query or work on VPS configuration and find a bottleneck that can generate such time.

**Table STATPOINTS:**

[image: Statpoints]

**Table USERS:**

[image: Users]

I do not know if I have given you an insight into the tables, when it comes to something else I would ask for guidance.

**Explain:**

[image: Explain]

Comment: Show your table and indexes.

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant to this particular issue?

Comment: You can improve the hardware all you want, but if the *database* is not optimized, it will still be slow. Use `explain`, and add indexes on the columns that will be heavily queried.

Comment: Your query is groupin by a column that can be null (`s.id_owner`). Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: It may be null, but there is virtually no chance of it occurring. 
I used Explain and updated the thread in the screenshot of the given action. 
[Forgive me for not embracing me]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can run faster if you add the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on user (bana, authlevel, universe);

create index ix2 on test_statpoints (stat_type, id_owner);

create index ix3 on test_planets (id_owner);
```

They include the access columns according to the join predicates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Score:
 Showing rows 0 - 24 (1078 total, Query took 0.0803 seconds.)